# WPF Datepicker to disable user input

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I have a datepicker, but it is allowing me to enter any text. I want to disable user from entering text. User should be allowed to select date from the calendar.

```
<Window x:Class="MyTestForDatePicker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <!--<Grid>-->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <DatePicker Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="2" Name="MySelectedDate"     VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ></DatePicker>
        <DatePickerTextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2" Name="SelectedDate"   IsReadOnly="True"></DatePickerTextBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="100,102,203,154" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Name="Ok" Click="Ok_Click_1"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Why not just have a reguar, read-only text box print the value of the date once it's been picked? Why do you need a `<DatePickerTextBox>` specifically, if it's going to be read-only?

Comment: Why is "entering any text" a problem? `24 May 2013` is a perfectly valid date. Why punish users who prefer to use keyboard? It is much quicker to type `24/5/13` than to muck about with a mouse and picker control.

Comment: @CraigYoung: so you don't have to muck around with validating garbage input, and the binding errors that would result.

Comment: @BCA I'm not sure if you correctly understand my comment. Question wants to "disable user from entering text(full stop)". Most modern controls in most languages provide a fairly easy way to validate keyboard input. Do you think it's better to muck about trying to fight default control behaviour than to ask out how to work _within the existing framework_ to provide a better experience for all kinds of users?

Comment: @CraigYoung: I understand what you're saying. However, when doing MVVM databinding, there is a scenario where the binding fails due to bad input (e.g. "2016-05-a3") and the viewmodel has no awareness of this error, hence cannot validate properly. There are workarounds but are complicated. In some simple use cases it makes more sense to constrain the user's selection to a valid `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 42):

seems like there is no property on DatePicker to make the TextBox read only.

Try the below style setting

```
        <DatePicker x:Name="MyDatePicker">
            <DatePicker.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                </Style>
            </DatePicker.Resources>
        </DatePicker>
```

Comment: @krishnaaditya what is solution for RadDatePicker?

Comment: @krish Ooooh thats a nice spot is that!

Comment: Partially works, the user can still click on the date button on the right hand side of the control and select a new date.

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz : The question does specify "User should be allowed to select date from the calendar", so the answer is still perfectly good.

Comment: Downvote. This actually does not work. "The member IsReadOnly is not recognized or is not accessible." This is WPF in VS2015. Tried it both in the DatePicker and also in the Style. Does. Not. Work.

Comment: Yes, this also did not work for me in VS 2019.  However the answer that did work is below.

Comment: how can I clear the datepicker's selected date if it is readonly?

Answer (score 24):

Add the property

`Focusable = "False"`

to your datepicker. This should not allow user to enter any string in datepicker textbox

```
<DatePickerTextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="2" Name="SelectedDate"   IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False"></DatePickerTextBox>
```

Comment: This works even better. I had a problem where the date text get auto selected when I pick a date and `IsReadOnly=True` solves it.

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same question and this is what worked for me. This blocks the textbox while still allowing the date picker to be used.

Answer (score 11):

Set the `IsHitTestVisible` and `Focusable` properties to `false`.

Comment: Thanks! if you want to disable input in the text and disable the user being able to select from the calendar button, this is the way to go!  DatePicker did not have IsReadOnly property.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me (global style for all datepickers):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy', RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Be aware: it also sets a custom string format.

Answer (score 0):

No need to set any thing to datepicker, when you out focus datepicker will remove text automatically, only date was remain in textbox.

Answer (score -3):

Just set the IsEnabled to false and that should solve your problem