# How do I programmatically disable DatePicker?

Tags: wpf

There are times I want to disable DatePicker.  These do not work:

```
gDPickDate.ReadOnly = "True";
gDPickDate.IsReadOnly = "True";
```

The complier complains about gDPickDate.ReadOnly and gDPickDate.IsReadOnly.  It never compiles.

How do I programmatically disable DatePicker?

I have found posts about doing this via WPF.  I have not seen any via a C# command.

Comment: which language?

Comment: How do these not work? I guess both of them are `bool` or `bool?` typed properties, so assigning strings can't work. Did you try `gDPickDate.IsEnabled = false;`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF Datepicker to disable user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740451/wpf-datepicker-to-disable-user-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DPickDate.IsEnabled works --- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/89090c37-d029-46f7-bb86-ff66c651f247/how-do-i-programmatically-disable-datepicker?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        gDPickDate.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        gDPickDate.Focusable = false;
```