# Datepicker input text

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, bootstrapper

Iam using a datepicker field, I could add text inside the field even after giving the date.

How do we restrict user to enter alphabets in a datepicker field?

I tried with singleinputs=false

Comment: Please provide problematic code, we don't what datepicker you talking about

Answer (score 1):

If you change the **onkeydown** event the user won't be able to add additional values, it will only allow to pick Date values as intendend.

```
<input onkeydown="return false" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

[WPF Datepicker to disable user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740451/wpf-datepicker-to-disable-user-input)

nice solution before, probably as mentioned in above url

```
                    <DatePicker x:Name="dp1"   Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="532,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <DatePicker.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DatePicker.Resources>
                    </DatePicker>
```